# Add property to each object in JSON C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a JSON body which looks like this(an array of objects):

```
[
    {
        "registered": "2016-02-03T07:55:29",
        "color": "red",
    },
    {
        "registered": "2016-02-03T17:04:03",
        "color": "blue",
    }
]
```

This body is contained in a variable(requestBody) I create based on a HTTP Request, it's called req:

```
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

What I want to do is add a unique identifier to each one of the objects in my JSON array. How could I go about achieving this?

Currently I am deserializing the JSON, adding some string(x) to it and then serializing it again:

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
d.uniqueId = "x";
string newBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

I was to add a uniqueId to each one of the objects in my JSON array of objects. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JArray` from [LINQ to JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to parse, iterate children of `JObject` type and modify them:

```cs
var json = ...; // your json string
var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach (var jObject in jArray.Children<JObject>())
{
    jObject.Add("id", new JValue("x"));
}
var modified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray);
```

Comment: Another one for you @Guru Stron

Assuming I want to make the id property to be unique. Let's say I want the "id" property to be a combination of registered and color(the other properties that already exist in my JSON body. How would I go about making "id" a combination of the 2 properties(color and registered)?